# Angular 2: why no empty element tags?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Why can I not use empty element tags in my ng2 template. It is the same with the section as with a file in templateUrl.

```
<p></p>    // OK

<p/>       // NOK (endless "Loading...")
```

???

cheers,
chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` tag is not a non closing element in html. The non-closing elements are e.g. `img`, `input` or `br`. If you don't close it - the loading will be shown endlessly because the compiler will throw a **template parse error**:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "p" ("
</p>
[ERROR ->]<p/>
```

Comment: I do not see that error. But the compiler prints "Build successful" as usually. I started with "ng serve". But it is "Loading..." forever.
Do I need to set something?

Comment: @chris01 Open the console and you will see it.

Comment: I see, its in the JS console of the browser, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 only allows valid HTML5 in component templates.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/217408

> - In **HTML5**, the meaning of `<foo />` [depends on the type of element][1].
>
>   - On HTML elements that are designated as *void
>       elements*, end tags are simply forbidden. The slash at the end of the
>       start tag is allowed, but has no meaning. It is just syntactic sugar
>       for people (and syntax highlighters) that are addicted to XML.
>   - On
>       other HTML elements, the slash is an error, but error recovery will
>       cause browsers to ignore it and treat the tag as a regular start tag.
>       This will usually end up with a missing end tag causing subsequent
>       elements to be children instead of siblings.
>   - Foreign elements
>       (imported from XML applications such as SVG) treat it as self-closing
>       syntax.
>
>   [1]: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags